# Date Formatting Returns Nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm getting nil when trying to create a date from a string. What am I doing wrong?

```
let createdAt = passesDictionary["createdAt"] as? String
print(createdAt)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let createdDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(createdAt!)
print(createdDate)
```

createdAt is Optional("2016-05-03T19:17:00.434Z"), but createdDate is nil.

Comment: Your date format does not match the format of your string

Answer (score 1):

The date string `"2016-05-03T19:17:00.434Z"` does match the pattern you gate to [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) ("yyyy-MM-dd"). Try this pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Here's [a table of the tokens](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) you can use in the `dateFormat`, as linked from the Apple documentation.

Comment: This answer simply states the obvious. It does not help the user solve the problem.

Comment: BTW - there was no need to post this answer since this question has been asked and answered hundreds of times before. Always look for duplicates before posting an answer.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in the future